# Solr | Get top user searched queries and use for auto-suggest feature like GSA does

Tags: solr, autosuggest

I am using solr-7.x

For auto-suggest feature, the requirement is to take the top searched user query terms and populate the suggest. Out of the 15 collections, I need this requirement for 2 collections.

I went through few articles but could not get if Solr has a way to achieve this requirement.

Terms component - give most frequently appeared terms in index. Anything of this sort that could returns same from queries?

Apart from reading logs, is there an API in solr that could return all user queries?

Problem with reading logs - in production the log level is usually Error and info logs with queries cant be read.

https://lucidworks.com/2009/09/08/auto-suggest-from-popular-queries-using-edgengrams/#comment-242860

Answer (score 0):

No, Solr does not have this capability built-in.

And since Solr does not have the capability built-in, there is no exposed API to retrieve that information.

The logs are your friend - [Solr 7.5 uses log4j2](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/configuring-logging.html#permanent-logging-settings), so you can defined an explicit logger that only logs INFO messages (and from a given endpoint/module) to a specific file or destination. You then ingest this log into your top queries feature and extract the queries as needed.

Comment: In your last line - you said"top queries feature"? Is there anything of that sort in Solr?

Comment: No. My assumption is that you've created something externally to supply that.